# Windows Loads Webpage on Startup - How do I stop this?

Tags: windows-8, boot, firefox

Recently (within the last couple of weeks) I noticed that Windows 8.1 is opening my default browser (Firefox) and opening a page (http://www.microsoft.com/th-th/default.aspx) every time Windows starts.

I've checked and disabled everything I can in my Task Manager > Startup. I've also checked the active tasks in the Take Scheduler library, but it's a formidable list and I really don't know which task could be causing this behavior.

How can I pinpoint what process is responsible for this?

Comment: Just to be sure, run Malware bytes or similar. Just a precaution!

Comment: Thank you! I just installed, updated, and ran Malware Bytes. No hint of an infection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several ways this is launching:

1) Startup options as you rightly said.  By disabling processed in Task Manager > Startup, you should be able to eliminate this

2) Registry Startup.  Check all of the following registry keys and see if it is launching from there:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
```

3) Auto start for users.  Check:

```
Autostart for currently logged-on user: shell:startup = %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

And startup folder all users: shell:common startup = %programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

These should do for a starter.  As for finding which process is spawning an application - I am not sure.

I've had limited success in the past by changing permissions on the executable (in this case firefox.exe) and then checking event viewer to see which application threw up an exception (error when launching application type errors).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of those places where it could be. I've checked each one of them, and there is nothing in them that I haven't asked for. (Except Adobe Autostarter! Adobe are so heavy handed.)

Comment: In that case, I have a feeling that it may well be another App which is starting  and making this launch.  Does it happen in Safe mode?

Comment: Solved! Unfortunately I can't track down exactly what fixed it. I unticked a bunch of stuff using 'Autoruns' software, and I also deleted a registry key or more related to Adobe. Unfortunately I made a mistake when backing-up my registry, and didn't actually back up the entire thing. So I can't compare the current registry state to the previous one to see exactly what I changed. Anyway, I'm really grateful for your help, and happy that my computer feels clean again.

Comment: good... if you need to, you can always start enabling them one by one and see when the problem reappears - that will give you an exact proces.. but if you have to reboot every time it will take ages.  Probably not worth the effort

Answer (score 2):

This seems like malware, or at least ad-ware, possibly incompletely installed (since it doesn't go directly to the wrong site). Check the browsers (including IE) for add-ons. [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) and [Kaspersky Security Scan](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner) are free antivirus scanners, and free [Avast!](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index) also has a browser extension check.

If you want to find the cause of startup, use free [Autoruns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Sysinternals (now run by MS). It lists *all* applications, services and Explorer add-ons, can validate them all at VirusTotal, and can be filtered and searched.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip on Autoruns. I'd never seen that software before, and it's very useful.

Comment: And also thanks for the tip on malware. I've now got a paid version of Bitdefender running (as well as periodic Malwarebytes scans scheduled). I feel my computer is more secure now, even though neither Malwarebytes nor Bitdefender (nor Nod ESET, which I also installed, briefly) found anything suspicious.

Comment: Your welcome, and glad to know that your machine is clean!